# Removing rows with * prefixed string

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame which is as given below

```
85  P   74  P   70  P   35  P   38  P   54
49  P   35  P   30  P   50  P   30  P   30
104 P   69  P   50  P   70  P   70  P   87
*44 P   *35 P   8   F   10  F   9   F   *37
*53 P   30  P   *40 P   30  P   *48 P   *73
76  P   86  P   69  P   84  P   66  P   79
110 P   65  P   40  P   57  P   57  P   74
```

I need to remove all the rows that have string starting with * using R. tried `gsub` and `sqldf` but I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: It is helpful if you supply your data in [a reproducible way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), perhaps using `dput`.

Comment: try with `grepl` instead of `gsub`

Answer (score 2):

something like this :

```
df2<-df[!apply(df,1,function(rg){any(grepl("^\\*[a-zA-Z1-9]",rg))}),]
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` to the rescue:

```
dat[-unique(unlist(lapply(dat, grep, pattern="^\\*" ))),]

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
#1  85  P 74  P 70  P 35  P 38   P  54
#2  49  P 35  P 30  P 50  P 30   P  30
#3 104  P 69  P 50  P 70  P 70   P  87
#6  76  P 86  P 69  P 84  P 66   P  79
#7 110  P 65  P 40  P 57  P 57   P  74
```

Alternative:

```
dat[!do.call(mapply, c(any, lapply(dat, grepl, pattern="^\\*" )) ),]
```

Alternative 2:

```
dat[!rowSums(sapply(dat, grepl, pattern="^\\*" ))>0,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
dat[!rowSums(`dim<-`(grepl("^\\*", as.matrix(dat)), dim(dat))),]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
#1  85  P 74  P 70  P 35  P 38   P  54
#2  49  P 35  P 30  P 50  P 30   P  30
#3 104  P 69  P 50  P 70  P 70   P  87
#6  76  P 86  P 69  P 84  P 66   P  79
#7 110  P 65  P 40  P 57  P 57   P  74
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(435)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:70, 5e3*5e3, replace=TRUE), ncol=5e3))
set.seed(25)
indx1 <- sample(1:nrow(dat), 50)
indx2 <- sample(1:ncol(dat), 50)
dat[cbind(indx1, indx2)] <- paste0("*", dat[cbind(indx1, indx2)])


f1 <- function() dat[Reduce(intersect, lapply(dat, grep, pattern = "^[^*]")), ]
f2 <- function() dat[-unique(unlist(lapply(dat, grep, pattern="^\\*" ))),]
f3 <- function() dat[!do.call(mapply, c(any, lapply(dat, grepl, pattern="^\\*" )) ),]
f4 <- function() dat[!rowSums(sapply(dat, grepl, pattern="^\\*" ))>0,]
f5 <- function() dat[!rowSums(`dim<-`(grepl("^\\*", as.matrix(dat)), dim(dat))),]
f6 <- function() dat[!apply(dat,1,function(rg){any(grepl("^\\*[a-zA-Z1-9]",rg))}),]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), f6(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#expr       min        lq     mean   median        uq      max neval cld
#f1() 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000    20  a 
#f2() 1.0027468 0.9161133 1.016727 1.114290 0.9195075 1.349399    20  a 
#f3() 3.5439827 3.2813344 3.780002 4.030356 3.5895574 4.209253    20   b
#f4() 3.3107041 3.7476493 4.226460 3.981993 4.0828441 6.023643    20   b
#f5() 0.8852371 0.8952590 0.952933 1.075323 0.9116219 0.881139    20  a 
#f6() 0.9693086 0.9810031 1.044375 1.086053 1.0062910 1.189163    20  a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` and `Reduce` (and three other functions, `grep`, `intersect`, and `[`):

```
dat[Reduce(intersect, lapply(dat, grep, pattern = "^[^*]")), ]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
# 1  85  P 74  P 70  P 35  P 38   P  54
# 2  49  P 35  P 30  P 50  P 30   P  30
# 3 104  P 69  P 50  P 70  P 70   P  87
# 6  76  P 86  P 69  P 84  P 66   P  79
# 7 110  P 65  P 40  P 57  P 57   P  74
```

Answer (score 2):

`paste` the rows together, `grepl` the ones with stars and take those not matched:

```
DF[!grepl("*", do.call(paste, DF), fixed = TRUE), ]
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
1  85  P 74  P 70  P 35  P 38   P  54
2  49  P 35  P 30  P 50  P 30   P  30
3 104  P 69  P 50  P 70  P 70   P  87
6  76  P 86  P 69  P 84  P 66   P  79
7 110  P 65  P 40  P 57  P 57   P  74
```